# File not found Error SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I am working with SharePoint 2010. I was making some changes to master pages of my site.
Then this error started coming

The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Could you please help me on this.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I resolved the problem. It was some custom mater applied to central admin not known to me. It had the ascx path problem (~/) was missing. On restoring the path everything is working fine. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might have referred an image or style sheet or some file from an invalid path. Check the error in detail, where you might be able to know which file or file path is not correct. Then recorrect it in the master page and then refresh the site.

**UPDATE** - Can you configure the web.config to display the detailed error? 
Make - `<CustomErrors Mode="Off">`, `CallStack="true"` and `<compilation debug="true" />`

Do an IISReset and then refresh the site.

Comment: Well I was just changing the properties of TopNavigation But I have reset the master page. Still id dint help.

Comment: Now some pages of Central Admin and some of my site collection are accessible like "Site Settings" etc. But not others.I doubt some master page has problem.Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: apply v4.master as the custom master page and check if you are able to access the pages. If yes, then scrutinize your custom master page with path errors. If not, please detail the error that you are getting.

Comment: I tried to change the master page but still no luck. I checked the logs and the error its logging is about unsafe controls on master page.That the controls on master page are not registered as safe hence the master page is breaking all the pages.

Comment: Unsafe controls on master page means there are some web parts or user control referred at the top of your custom master page that has not been registered safe in the web.config. This wont usually happen for default master pages. See this link for more info - http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/05/23/sharepoint-register-an-assembly-as-a-safe-control-in-the-web-config-file.aspx . Remove those entries from the master page or register them as type safe in your web.config. It should work.

Comment: Now I am getting the following error " /_catalogs/masterpage/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx does not exist. I have googled for this and the cause for this has been truncation of "~/" from the src attribute of these controls. Though I have put corrected the path but still default master is not loading.Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you try my solution posted for this similar question? - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30070/ive-screwed-something-up-in-2007-only-in-the-backend-apparently

Comment: I tried your solution I put the (~/) back in the path and my ascx controls exist as well at the said path.Still no luck.

Comment: View my updates in answer.