# I've screwed something up in 2007, only in the backend apparently

Tags: 2007, error, site, settings

When I try to "modify all site settings" I get the following error:

The file '/_layouts/MasterPages/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx' does not exist.   at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)

(...etc...)

In my masterpage, this is the line in question (I think):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
```

Why does it think the root garnered from the tilde is the masterpages folder?  Or is that even the problem?

Thanks, I'm an idiot.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Chris maybe you have deleted the file. Since it is an application file you have to repair your sharepoint installation to resolve that. Or you can just go to another server running sharepoint copy the file Welcome.ascx and paste it in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\template\controltemplates (considering a default path installation)

Comment: The file is there that I can see. But is it looking in the right place? It seems like it wants to find controltemplates in the masterpages folder: /_layouts/MasterPages/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet should look like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
```

with the `~` sign in front of the path in src attribute. If you try to edit your master page in SharePoint designer, it might truncate the `~` sign automatically. Try editing it in Visual Studio or simply open it in notepad, add the '~' sign and save it. It should be resolved.

Comment: I tried this, but VS complained about opening a sharepoint site.  One thing I'm REALLY confused about is when I make edits to the master page in SP Designer, I see the edits only when logged in to the SP site.  The SP site allows anonymous access and when not logged in, everyone sees the old version.  It's like my master page edits are not saving to the public facing version.

Comment: Did you checkin, publish and approve your master page. Then others might be able to see the changes.